Can't ping from Windows host to Pfsense LAN interfaces in VMWare Workstation
I have a Windows uses Vmware Workstation including PFsense virtual machine.
The WAN card is configured with VMWare's NAT and the other interfaces (LAN, OPT1, OPT2,..) are configured with LAN Segment.
The problem is I can't ping from Windows host to the VMs behind the PFsense (LAN, OPT1, OPT2,..) firewall except for the WAN. Meanwhile, it can be done vice versa, all the LAN interfaces can ping each other or to the Windows host successfully.
I  set the Pfsense rules to pass any of the protocols on every interfaces and configured the static routes on Windows host too but it does not work.
The only succesful ping is to the PFsense WAN but not other interfaces behind it. When I switched the WAN interface to VM bridge mode then it works but this is VMWare NAT mode so I think that is where the problem at.
My interface assigments:
pfsense
Ping from Windows host:
C:\Users\Admin>ping 192.168.232.9

Pinging 192.168.232.9 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.232.9: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.232.9: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.232.9: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.232.9: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.232.9:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\Admin>ping 192.168.30.11

Pinging 192.168.30.11 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.30.11:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),


My route print :
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
     192.168.30.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.232.1       1
     192.168.40.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.232.1       1
     192.168.20.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.232.1       1

